# How can i make the highlighting Dropdown with transperent background

Tags: html, css, highlighting

I want to make a custom dropdown with an image instead of this annoying arrow 
So  in this forum  someone suggested to wrap the select in a smaller div. So everything works. 
The problem is with selection.

when i select an option you know the blue background highlighting  that indicates the selected element and the problem is even when the elements is selected this highlighting stays overlaying my image arrow.

How can i solve this

I've tried to use the selection optin but nothing happened!

```
.styled-select select option ::selection {
       background:#fff;

}
```

Here is my code:
**HTML**

```
        <div class="styled-select">
       <select>
          <option>Here is the first option</option>
          <option>The second option</option>
       </select>
        </div>
```

**CSS:-**

```
    .styled-select select {
       background: transparent;
       width: 268px;
       padding: 5px;
        border: 0;
       border-radius: 0;
       height: 34px;
       line-height: 1;
       -webkit-appearance: none;
       }

    .styled-select {
       width: 240px;
       height: 34px;
       overflow: hidden;
       background: url(file:///C:/Users/gismo2/Pictures/fancy_nav_down.jpg) no-repeat right  ;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to style a dropdown i suggest using a plugin like:
[Jquery Selectbox](http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/)

This dropdown you can style to your needs!